# how to stop loader once page is mounted in vue js

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, vue-loader

please i want the loader to load before contents are displayed on the page and stop when the content has been displayed

this is my loader

```
     <div v-if="isLoading">
        <loader
          object="#ff9633"
          color1="#ffffff"
          color2="#17fd3d"
          size="5"
          speed="2"
          bg="#343a40"
          objectbg="#999793"
          opacity="80"
          name="circular"
        ></loader>

      </div>
```

this is my script tag

```
<script>
import { Carousel, Slide } from "vue-snap";
import "vue-snap/dist/vue-snap.css";
export default {
  name: "App",
  components: {
    Carousel,
    Slide
  },
  data() {
    return {
      isLoading: false
    };
  },
  mounted() {
    longAjaxRequest.then(res => {
      this.isLoading = true;
      setTimeout(() => {
        this.isLoading = false;
      }, 3000);
    });
  }
};
</script
```

like this the loader doesn't work until i set isLoading = true

please how can i achieve

Comment: within the `then()` of your ajax request, the request is already done at that point.  just put `this.isLoading = true;` before the request starts

Comment: you should set `isLoading: false` to true since it is loading. then set it false once you have loaded, leaving out the setTimeout, also the v-if="isLoading" can go on the component

Comment: @LawrenceCherone setting isLoading:true makes it keeps loading

Comment: @yoduh doesn't do anything

Comment: it would since longAjaxRequest is undefined so it won't reach the callback to set it to false, if your real code is different then add it to show what you have tried and changed

Comment: Set isLoading true before the request, set isLoading false after the request is done.  In case your ajaxRequest returns an error make sure to also set to false in any `catch` or `finally` block you may have.  This is the basic idea: [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/confident-joliot-nyh98i?file=/src/App.vue)